# When I type a style on CSS and then the other only the first one gets styled

Tags: html, css

This is an example of what my problem is. When I type for example the
section on html then go to CSS to style it, it does work fine, but
then when I add another style in the CSS file it doesn't seem to work
and only styles the first part so in this case the .header img and the
h1 part doesn't get styled at all. When I put the h1 part in front of
the .header only h1 gets styled and not the .header img. Inline CSS
works but its very inconvenient to use. This happens even when I try
using the  inside the html document. I have tried it on
other text editors and it's the same problem. When I try someone
else's code it works fine, it's only when I do it on a project that
does this.

```css
.header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

;
h1 {
  color: aqua;
}

;
```

```html
<section class="header">
  <img src="/download.png">
</section>

<h1>asdad</h1>
```

Comment: You need to remove the semicolons between definitions.

Comment: You have a stray semi colon in the CSS just before the h1 settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of your css code is wrong. There cannot be semicolons outside .class{}
You should remove semicolons before and after your h1{} style.

Comment: It should be closed as a typo.

Comment: Thank you I didn't see that!